# Error when Running Codecept

Tags: php, linux, codeception

I am trying to run a test and when I use the codecept command I get this error. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

**Error**: **Internal script failure**

```
codecept run tests/acceptance/RequestCept.php --steps
==== Redirecting to Composer-installed version in vendor/codeception 
====
<br />
<b>Error</b>: <font color="FF0000"><b>Internal script failure</b><br />
```

Comment: Can you show us the code causing the error?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that a needed file was missing. (It exists on the guest file, but not on the host file)

*Issue Resolved*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `--debug` (or `-d`) to show the scenario debug?

Also, can you put some code helping us finding where the failure could be in your script?

Comment: Yes, I tried both of those options, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed with composer? `php composer.phar require "codeception/codeception"`